# Getting error 404 while trying to run flask app in python

Tags: python, flask

[attached is the picture of how my directories are up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6c20.png)i am trying to run my app with flask, and I am referencing the proper directories, yet I keep getting an error 404 message. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my the code to run the app in the app.py section:

```
    @app.route('/')
    def math():
        #return(y)
        return render_template('index2.html', variable = y)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug = True)
```

and here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Scrolling Nav - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="/static2/static2/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="/static2/static2/css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="/static2/static2/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/static2/static2/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
  <script src="/static2/static2/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom JavaScript for this theme -->
  <script src="/static2/static2/js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

the scrolling -nav.js is in the correct folder for sure.

Please let me know if there is more information needed for this question.

Answer (score 0):

For references to static files in Flask it's considered best practice to use the `url_for` function e.g.

```
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/scrolling-nav.js')}}"></script>
```

Other than that, if that is your full HTML then it's just a javascript file, do you have the basic HTML stuff in there as well? e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    Content
    </body>
<html>
```

Is `index2.html` stored in a templates folder?

Comment: I have other basic html in there as well. theres a lot more error 404s showing up I just picked that line as an example. And index2.html is in a templates folder yes.

Comment: What url are you using to access the page? e.g. http://127.0.0.1:80/

Comment: 127.0.0.1:2000 im running the flask app as usual but custom setting the port to 2000

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Only going from the code there the only other thing that stads out is "variable = y" but in your example "y" doesn't exist so you might be getting an error because of that

Comment: no errors in the console. The variable y is defined, i just didnt include it in the question. Should i show more of my code?

Comment: Yea I think to help further you'll need to show more code please

Comment: ok I added a picture of how my directories are set up, and I added more of my html code

Answer (score 0):

I got it. My directories name was static2. The directories name must be "static" for the css and js files to be pulled.